# Issue with adding new empty row in a gridview control using a button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've a gridview which is forever in an edit mode(Pageload). I've added a button at the footer of the gridview in order to add a new row to insert values. Now, the problem is that when I want to edit the data from database. The data will bind into the gridview and if I click on the button to add new row, the data which was already exist in the gridview will disappear except the 1st row.

This the code under add new row button:

```
private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["TempTable"] != null)
        {
            // Get TempTable from viewstate
            var tempTable = (DataTable)ViewState["TempTable"];
            DataRow tempRow = null;

            if (tempTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= tempTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    // Get Grid's values                    
                    var txtProblem =
                        (TextBox)gvTroubleshooting.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtProblem");
                    var txtCorrectiveMessure =
                        (TextBox)gvTroubleshooting.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtCorrectiveMessure");

                    // Create new row and update Row Number
                    tempRow = tempTable.NewRow();
                    tempTable.Rows[i - 1]["Problem"] = txtProblem.Text;
                    tempTable.Rows[i - 1]["Corrective_Measures"] = txtCorrectiveMessure.Text;

                    rowIndex++;
                }
                // Add data to datatable and viewstate
                tempTable.Rows.Add(tempRow);
                ViewState["TempTable"] = tempTable;

                // Attach Gridview Datasource to datatable
                gvTroubleshooting.DataSource = tempTable;
                gvTroubleshooting.DataBind();
            }
        }

        //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
        SetPreviousData();
    }
```

SetPreviousData() code is as follows:

```
private void SetPreviousData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["TempTable"] != null)
        {
            var tempTable = (DataTable)ViewState["TempTable"];

            if (tempTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < tempTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var txtProblem =
                        (TextBox)gvTroubleshooting.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtProblem");
                    var txtCorrectiveMessure =
                        (TextBox)gvTroubleshooting.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtCorrectiveMessure");

                    txtProblem.Text = tempTable.Rows[i]["Problem"].ToString();
                    txtCorrectiveMessure.Text = tempTable.Rows[i]["Corrective_Measures"].ToString();

                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: its simpler to put empty textboxes on footer and then add new item when you click on the button. can you do that?

Comment: I don't want to do that way, because its just an option for them to add more. Basically it is an edit form

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your existing datagridview data to a temporary datatable and merge it with the newly added datatable.Now set the merged datatable as your datasource to the datagridview